# Monitoring Reachability with AFNetworking in unit test fails

Tags: objective-c, unit-testing, afnetworking-2, reachability, ocmock

In a project I am working I have implemented the [HTTP Manager Reachability](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking#http-manager-reachability) example.

When I run the **actual app**, it goes inside the block and from there to the switch:

```
[manager.reachabilityManager setReachabilityStatusChangeBlock:^(AFNetworkReachabilityStatus status) {
switch (status) {
```

In addition, when I call `...reachabilityManager] isReachable` method returns true as expected.

The problem occurs when I try to **unit test** a class method I wrote that uses `...reachabilityManager] isReachable` as a precondition - it returns false and what is weird that during a debug I have noticed that it doesn't go inside the above block, it skips it.

Of course, in the actual app it goes inside the block.

I have even tried to mock the class that implements the HTTP Manager Reachability example using [OCMock](http://ocmock.org/) in the unit test but it gave me the same result:

```
// NetworkClass implements the example
NetworkClass *networkClass = [[NetworkClass alloc] init];
id mockedNetworkClass = OCMPartialMock(networkClass);
// startNetworkMonitoring method implements the whole example above
[mockedNetworkClass startNetworkMonitoring];
// Giving enough time for AFNetworking to finish
[NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:60.0f];
```

**EDIT1:**

Looks like semaphore/XCTestExpectation won't help, the problem is in *AFNetworkReachabilityManager::startMonitoring*:

- The only way that we could get the callback we want is inside *startMonitoring* method at `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
           callback(status);`

But it runs outside the unit test even if we use semaphore/XCTestExpectation as mentioned.

Still looking for soultions..

**EDIT2:**

I was trying to follow the [objc.io](https://www.objc.io/issues/15-testing/xctest/#don-t-be-alone-join-a-group) for *Testing Asynchronous Code* but it seems to be missing some code and some of the explanations are lacking of integration details.

Comment: I'm not sure of what you're trying to test for, but maybe you could capture the status change block and execute it with different parameters for different test cases. Would that make sense for you?

Comment: Actually no. As I wrote, I am trying to test a method that is doing something but the precondition to this method is the isReachable method and this, is the issue.

Comment: What if you mock the `manager.reachabilityManager` and stub the `isReachable` method to return YES always. This would allow you to do your tests. Notice that by actually using the Reachability object you are introducing a dependency in your test.

Comment: the problem is that OCMock cannot return primitives. OCMockito can, but that doesn't allow partial mocking. I'm still looking for a solution that can combine those two features.

Answer (score 1):

I'd imagine that sleeping the thread is causing issues.

Try using the expectations API documented in [Writing Tests of Asynchronous Operations](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/testing_with_xcode/chapters/04-writing_tests.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014132-CH4-SW6).

Something along the lines of this should get you started (note this is more of a demonstration of the expectations API rather than a complete working test case):

```
- (void)testReachability {
    XCTestExpectation *expectation = [self expectationWithDescription:@"Wait for reachability"];

    [manager.reachabilityManager setReachabilityStatusChangeBlock:^(AFNetworkReachabilityStatus status) {
        ...

        [expectation fulfill];

    }];

    [self waitForExpectationsWithTimeout:10 handler:^(NSError * _Nullable error) {
        // timed out waiting for reachability
    }];
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the respond.I tried and it fails. Also,I tried to use semaphore which is the same as XCTestExpectation and it also fails.  It never enters the block - keep in mind that during debug I have watched the basicNetwork object and it was fully initialized with the right URL.

Comment: I think that I have found the problem, while running the actual app the first call that reaches setReachabilityStatusChangeBlock DON'T goes into the block, only on the 2nd call (which is a callback by AFNetworking) it goes inside the block. So the question now is how to enable this callback (inside the unit testing) while unit test is actually synchronous...